# How can I amend the classes available to a custom Gradle task?

Tags: gradle, task, classpath

I wrote a custom Gradle task to encapsulate a Java application, https://github.com/ndw/xmlcalabash1-gradle

It's a fairly simple extension of `org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionTask` cobbled together somewhat quickly. It's entirely possible that I'm just doing it wrong.

It's been working just fine for a while now. I've used it in several projects. However, for the particular `build.gradle` that I'm writing now, I need to make additional classes available to it.

After much frustration and complete failure to get additional jars into the classpath, I went back and updated my application class so that it would print out its classpath. That revealed that when this task runs, the classpath consists of only `/usr/lib/gradle/4.4.1/lib/gradle-launcher-4.4.1.jar`. I conclude that some alternate class loader must be in use because the task does successfully load the core application classes.

Can anyone tell me how to make more jars available to my task? None of my web search foo has lead me to an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "make additional classes available to it"?

Comment: The app needs to instantiate com.acme.Thingy in this case, so I need to get the jar files that contain those classes on the classpath for execution of the app. I briefly thought that putting a fileTree(dir: 'lib').include('*.jar') in the buildscript closure was going to do the trick, but no such luck.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, for the love of all things. I left 'classpath' out of the dependencies in the buildscript closure. #facepalm.